# How to set creationUserID from user entity to the Accounts entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my application, when a user creates an account, it will pass the user details. The creationUserID in the ACCOUNT table is the userId of the User table. Below is the JSON request structure.

```json
{
    "accountNo":1001,
    "balance":4000,    
    "ownerOfTheAccount" : {
        "userID": 4,
        "fName" : "Dan",
        "lName":"Brown",
        "email" :"dan@brown"
    }
}
```

I want to set the creationUserID to the accounts entity. The creation user ID needs to taken from the user entity. How can I set the userID =4 in my example, as the creationUserID field in the ACCOUNT entity? I'm new to JPA.

```sql
create table ACCOUNT (
  account_number int (10) not null primary key,
  balance float (20) not null,
  user_id  varchar_ignorecase (25) not null,
  creation_date AS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
                 
  constraint fk_account_customer foreign key(user_id) references USERS(user_id)
);
```

User entity and Account entity have OneToOne mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set it manually. I'm not sure is there a way to set it in the entity bean itself. But I set it manually in the service layer.